# How to write multiline attributes in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2015

The latest releases of Visual Studio 2015 has left our entire cshtml mark-up in a very fragile state. Many times we have attribute values that exceed a usable width and we need to split the attribute up across multiple lines to make the code more readable.

Example : wide data-bind

```
<div data-bind="someBinding: { hasErrors: bindingObject.HasErrors(duration), hasWarnings: bindingObject.HasWarnings(duration), parameterKey: bindingObject.SelectedObjectKey }, anotherBinding: value, anotherBinding2: value2, AndSoOn: yaddayadda.the.point.is.this.can.get.really.long">
```

Back in VS 2010/2013 if we starting just putting carriage returns within the attribute value to break it up the designer would usually no longer parse the html appropriately and DOM elements following this would no longer be valid...such as a broken table.

So we found that by encapsulating the attribute value within @("...") would actually allow the designer to function smoothly.

Example : with @() attribute binding

```
<div data-bind="@("someBinding: { " +
    "hasErrors: bindingObject.HasErrors(duration), " +
    "hasWarnings: bindingObject.HasWarnings(duration), " +
    "parameterKey: bindingObject.SelectedObjectKey }, " +
    "anotherBinding: value, " +
    "anotherBinding2: value2, " + 
    "AndSoOn: yaddayadda.the.point.is.this.can.get.really.long")">
```

Well, the good news here is the IDE would even help with expanding this string and when the page reformatted itself it would be happy and the DOM was in great shape. The server would take this blob of C# string and render it to a single line in production and all was good...

Until we upgraded. VS2015 seems to detest this, but for entirely different reasons. Now it squiggles the entire thing and the tooltip says 'Missing Attribute Name'. When the page reformats it botches everything...

[image]

So I'm walking on glass here. Is this some sort of bug or is there an answer, cause we've got a big code base that doesn't want to go through having to refactor this attribute formatting.

Thoughts?

Comment: and, for the record, VS 2013 + R#10 does NOT exhibit this behavior...so I'm thinking this is only w/ VS 2015 + R#10

Comment: Could you temporarily suspend ReSharper and check if this warning still exists? I'm just wondering because there is no "Inspection 'xxx'" suppression menu.

Comment: Suspended and still the same behavior...so I think this is more associated with VS than R#...just interesting how R# provides relevant options to 'resolve' the non-problem...

Comment: You've already filed this [at connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2013852/how-to-write-multiline-attributes-in-visual-studio-2015), that's where it belongs since nobody here can fix VS2015 bugs.  You'll have to give them time to get to it, use a telephone and call Microsoft Support if you can't wait.

Comment: hope is that maybe it's not a bug and there's simply something I'm missing...nobody has even said they are having the same problem(s) here on SO, so I was going back through my questions and this one is still a bugger...keeping me in 2013 at times...

Comment: oh, and feel free to upvote that issue :: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2013852/how-to-write-multiline-attributes-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: I have tried using your example and am unable to reproduce this message using VS 2015 Update 1 and R#10.  I have noticed 2015 incorrectly displaying errors that have been fixed though.  Could you try deleting the `.vs` folder for this project to see if that helps?  Also, if there are old `.suo` files in there, delete them too.

Comment: @beauXjames by chance the file in question is a helper? is **inside App_Code** folder?

Comment: After Update 1, this problem appears to be resolved...along with quite a few others.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 contains a resolution to this problem.